# How to change only one value in LinkedList

Tags: java

I would like to change only one value, the second value (it is int) for example +1. How to do it? I would like to add to the below code for loop.

```
LinkedList<Ter> smList = new LinkedList<Ter>();

    smList.add(new Ter(2,4)); 
    smList.add(new Ter(5,9)); 
    smList.add(new Ter(6,5));  

     Iterator<Ter> iterator=smList.iterator();
     while(iterator.hasNext()){
       System.out.println(iterator.next());
     }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @CodeMatrix I have tried to add a for loop but It doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the second value that was passed into the constructor? ie do you want to, for example, change the first Ter object to have a state equivalent to new Ter(2,5), the second to new Ter(5,10)? If so, then the answer depends on the definition of the Ter class. Can you please provide a definition of the Ter class?

Comment: @JulianWright Yes I want to change the second value for all elements in LinkedList for example +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the second value in each `Ter` object and set the updated value to the object while iterating.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

class Ter {
    int x, y;

    public Ter(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Ter [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + "]";
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Ter> smList = new LinkedList<Ter>();
        smList.add(new Ter(2, 4));
        smList.add(new Ter(5, 9));
        smList.add(new Ter(6, 5));
        Iterator<Ter> iterator = smList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Ter ter = iterator.next();
            ter.setY(ter.getY() + 1);
        }
        System.out.println(smList);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Ter [x=2, y=5], Ter [x=5, y=10], Ter [x=6, y=6]]
```

**Note:**

If you want to use `for` loop instead of `while` loop (as you have requested in your comment), just replace

```
while (iterator.hasNext())
```

with

```
for (; iterator.hasNext();)
```

in my answer.

Comment: I would like to change to the second value +1 not add the third value to the LinkedList 
smList.add(new Ter(2,4));  change this to smList.add(new Ter(2,5)); and the all positions in LinkedList for the second value

Comment: @ggame - I've updated the answer. I hope, it meets your requirement.

Comment: Yes, I have checked answers. My question is how to use for this for loop not while.

Comment: @ggame - Just replace

`while (iterator.hasNext())`
with

`for (; iterator.hasNext();)` in my answer.

Comment: just replace it doesn't work, it is something wrong with for(int a=0; a< iterator.hasNext(); a++).

Comment: @ggame - Why do you want to put `a` in the `for` loop? Where are you going to use the value of `a`? The change I've suggested works perfectly. Simply copy and paste my whole code in your IDE and run it. That way, you'll understand it better. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Comment: I have executed in IDE but you told that only I can just replace while (iterator.hasNext()) with for (; iterator.hasNext();). I have to put somehing before and after iterator.hasNext()

Comment: @ggame - A `for` loop does not require you to put anything before or after `iterator.hasNext()` as I've suggested. You'are still worrying without trying it first. As I've mentioned, it will work perfectly. I strongly recommend you understand the `for` loop by studying https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the `Ter` class. If it is mutable (allows itself to be modified) and makes the value of the second argument to the constructor visible then you will be able to update that field inside your loop. If it is not mutable but still provides a getter for the corresponding field, then you can substitute a new Ter object with an updated second argument inside your loop.

So, lets start with a mutable `Ter` class:

```
public class Ter {

  private int first = 0;
  private int second = 0;

  public Ter(int a, int b) {
      first = a;
      second = b;
  }

  public int getFirst() {
      return first;
  }

  public void setFirst(int value) {
      first = value;
  }

  public int getSecond() {
      return second;
  }

  public void setSecond(int value) {
      second = value;
  }

  @override
  public String toString() {
      return "Ter[" + first + ", " + second + "]";
  }

}
```

Now you can write your main code like this:

```
List<Ter> smList = new LinkedList<>();
smList.add(new Ter(2,4)); 
smList.add(new Ter(5,9)); 
smList.add(new Ter(6,5));

Iterator<Ter> iterator=smList.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Ter ter = iterator.next();
    ter.setSecond(ter.getSecond() + 1);
    System.out.println(ter);
}
```

If on the other hand `Ter` is not mutable (doesn't have the setter methods above), then you will need to change each element of the list to a new one that has the desired second argument. There are several ways to do this, but in this case I suggest using the `ListIterator` provided by the `LinkedList`, as it has a `set()` method that is handy:

```
ListIterator<Ter> listIterator = smList.listIterator();
while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
    Ter ter = listIterator.next();
    Ter newTer = new Ter(ter.getFirst(), ter.getSecond() + 1);
    listIterator.set(newTer);
    System.out.println(newTer);
}
```

Output:

```
[Ter[2, 5], Ter[5, 10], Ter[6, 6]]
```

You could of course iterate over the list using an index variable and use the list's `get(index)` and `set(index, value)` methods, but that is not efficient for a `LinkedList`.

Hope this helps!